# Transform nested child elements to single element

Tags: xslt

I need to convert a some basic XHTML output from an WYSIWYG editor to a proprietairy typesetting XML format using XSLT.

The typesetting format may contain multiple `txt` elements, each which can have `bold`, `italic` and `underline` boolean attributes.

Now I want to be able to convert nested combinations of `<I>`, `<B>` and `<U>` tags and convert them to this XML format. For example:

```
 <block><b><i><u>BoldItalicUnderlined</u>BoldItalic</i>Bold</b></block>
```

To:

```
 <txt bold="true" italic="true" underlined="true">BoldItalicUnderlined</txt>
 <txt bold="true" italic="true" underlined="false">BoldItalicUnderlined</txt>
 <txt bold="true" italic="false" underlined="false">Bold</txt>
```

Can this be done with XSLT?

So far I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xls="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="mPass2">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="mPass2"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="block">
        <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1Result">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:apply-templates mode="mPass2" select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1Result)/*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <txt underline="false" italic="false" bold="false" the-text="true">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </txt>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="em|i">
        <txt underline="false" italic="true" bold="false" the-italic="true">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </txt>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="strong|b">
        <txt underline="false" italic="false" bold="true" the-bold="true">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </txt>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="u">
        <txt underline="true" italic="false" bold="false" the-underline="true">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </txt>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="txt[txt]" mode="mPass2" name="txt">
        <xsl:variable name="bold">
            <xsl:value-of select="@bold"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:for-each select="txt">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="mPass2"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which produces:

```
<txt underline="false" italic="false" bold="false">BoldItalicUnderlined</txt>
<txt underline="false" italic="false" bold="false">BoldItalic</txt>
<txt underline="false" italic="false" bold="false">Bold</txt>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//text()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space()='']"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <text bold="{boolean(ancestor::b)}" italic="{boolean(ancestor::i)}" underlined="{boolean(ancestor::u)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your answer!